# Why every update of most Applications means just redownloading the entire program

Tags: firefox, updates

Why even the most popular applications are asking its users to just redownload the entire program for just performing the updates.

For example consider FireFox. They are pushing updates with no major changes(most are security patches). So that would mean small changes. Then why can't the app be only modified only for that small change without downloading the whole program again?

What's preventing them from implementing that?

Comment: Firefox doesn't do that (atleast the one I have).

Comment: Yup, and chrome too.

Comment: Firefox does do delta releases but only for single version updates i.e. 23 to 24 or 40 to 41. If you've skipped an update then you'll be given a full update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too complicated to issue delta releases (which is the generally-used term for what you're asking for) as well as whole packages. You would have to release the whole package as well, so every delta release is additional effort. And you would have to test the additional release(s) on every supported platform, which for Firefox is a lot of tests, And if users have modified the package in any way, a delta release may break in exciting and unanticipated ways. And people will complain if they want to go from version 40 to version 44 and they have to either download the whole package or download four different delta releases, so you would end up having to do 43 different delta releases when you release version 44 of your program, one from each previous version.